# R store formula dynamically

Tags: r, formula, store

Let's assume a very simple MWE where we have a very basic formula for the first period:

```
x <- 0.75
Y_1 <- x^2
```

From the second period on, the formula is recursive and looks the same for all following periods (e.g. 5):

```
Y_2 <- x^2 + Y_1
Y_3 <- x^2 + Y_2
...
```

To calculate the recursive part, I create a loop and store the results in a list:

```
Y_i <- list(Y_1)

for(i in 1:5){
  Y_i <-  c(Y_i, list(Y_1 + (Y_i[[length(Y_i)]])))
}
```

This way I can store the LHS (Y_1, Y_2, Y_3,...) in the list. I wonder how I can also store the RHS (formula with values) in e.g. a list. I need the RHS for further calculations and so I have to store it dynamically because of the recursive part.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them as functions:

```r
Y_i <- list(Y_1)
F_i <- as.function(c(list(), as.call(list(Y_1))))

for(i in 1:5){
  Y_i <-  c(Y_i, list(Y_1 + (Y_i[[length(Y_i)]])))
  F_i <- c(F_i, as.function(c(list(), 
                as.call(list(quote(`+`), e1 = Y_1, e2 = Y_i[[length(Y_i)]])))))
}

F_i
#> [[1]]
#> function () 
#> 0.5625()
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> function () 
#> 0.5625 + 1.125
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> function () 
#> 0.5625 + 1.6875
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> function () 
#> 0.5625 + 2.25
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> function () 
#> 0.5625 + 2.8125
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> function () 
#> 0.5625 + 3.375
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand your objective in a correct way, below is my attempt by defining a recursive function `f`

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return(list(x**2))
  }
  u <- f(x, n - 1)
  uend <- u[[length(u)]]
  c(u, list(append(uend, x**2 + uend[length(uend)])))
}
```

such that

```
> f(0.75, 5)
[[1]]
[1] 0.5625

[[2]]
[1] 0.5625 1.1250

[[3]]
[1] 0.5625 1.1250 1.6875

[[4]]
[1] 0.5625 1.1250 1.6875 2.2500

[[5]]
[1] 0.5625 1.1250 1.6875 2.2500 2.8125
```